# Android - Manipulating view position during onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have made a simple dice game that makes use of the `setTranslationY()` method to indicate if a dice should be ignored for the next dice roll. This all works fine, except that when I try to restore the state of the app after a screen rotation, my restoring method cannot seem to use `setTranslationY()` on the views that need it.

I have confirmed time and time again the the method IS being called for all views that should be nudged upwards a little bit, but the views stay where they are.

If it is so that the app needs to go through the process of completing `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onResume()` before being able to manipulate views then please advise on how to achieve this. I need this to happen consistently upon every device rotation.

Comment: Can you share your code and in particular the way you save and restore the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain the state of your application by informing Android you'd like to [handle the logic for screen orientation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) yourself, rather than allowing the OS to trash and rebuild the entire `Activity` whenever the user tilts the screen. You can do this by adding the **`android:configChanges`** attribute to the `Activity` entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This should hopefully preserve the state of your animated `View`s.

Comment: It did! Thank you, I will look through the documentation so I properly understand the configChanges tag.